# Is an unfavorited track in an autoplaylist of favorites going to be removed from the device?

Tags: zune, sync

I have a pretty big music library, which exceeds the device's memory size, and I sync only favorited tracks by creating an autoplaylist. I listen them for some time, and then I decide to unfavorite one of them (on my phone).

Is it going to be removed from the device automatically (with or without syncing to the PC) or it will stay there until I erase it manually?

*I know, that I can test it by myself, but I noticed, that I tried to google it first, so, why not make a favor to other people and let them find the answer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you unfavourite a track on the phone, during the next synchronization it'll get removed from the device, device playlist and machine playlist. However, if you don't synchronize, the unfavourited song will remain on the device (and device playlist) till the next sync.

Answer (score 0):

You have some control over syncing the tracks you've labeled with a broken heart. In my screenshot below I've circled the toggle that you need to make sure you have checked. To get to this page you need to open Zune, click settings, then Phone and finally sync options.

Zune [image: Zune sync settings]